# Is there a way to get a list of all my categorical and numerical features in Pycaret?

Tags: installation, classification, pycaret, eda, categorical

I am using Pycaret for a classification problem and I want to get a list of all the categorical and numerical variables inferred by setup() for EDA. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried looking at any function in the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, I find only one way to do it in `PyCaret 3.x` by accessing the private variable of the Experiment object.

```
from pycaret.datasets import get_data
from pycaret.classification import *

data = get_data('bank', verbose=False)
exp = setup(data = data, target = 'deposit', session_id=123, verbose=False);

print(f'Ordinal features: {exp._fxs["Ordinal"]}')
print(f'Numeric features: {exp._fxs["Numeric"]}')
print(f'Date features: {exp._fxs["Date"]}')
print(f'Text features: {exp._fxs["Text"]}')
print(f'Categorical features: {exp._fxs["Categorical"]}')
```

[image]

Comment: Shows me this error:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_fxs'

Comment: What is your PyCaret version? If PyCaret 2.x it doesn't return as Experiment Object

Comment: Right, just checked it is 2.x
Is there a way to do this in that version?

Comment: For now, I still can't find a way to do it in 2.x

Comment: Do you think an issue can be made for this on Pycaret's Github?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think they are focusing on PyCaret 3.x that will release a stable version soon